# How can I run a batch job when start Jboss in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss

I use JBoss AS 5.0 with eclipse 3.6. I start Jboss inside eclipse, the problems is, eclipse start jboss by direclty calling run.jar, and I need to do some assembling job(file copying etc.) each time when I start the server, there's not where I can put this operation when I click the start button, are there any ways to run some pre-proccessing tasks before calling the main method of run.jar?

Comment: you want it to do it for your app or it is app independent ?

Comment: @Jigar Joshi I do it for my specific APP.

Comment: Workaround: you could head over to the external tools menu (menubar | Run | External Tools) and configure a custom run configuration, for instance, an external shell script that does "pre-processing". after its execution, you can run jboss.

Comment: and you need this setup @ runtime or at deployment time ?

Comment: @Jigar Joshi, I need this for development, it include two phase, first assembling resources into EAR and second start Jboss server. We have ant build file for the production deployment.

Comment: @phineas, if I use external tools, then I can call the assemble.bat, it only solved the first step. It won't start jboss inside eclipse. I have to click the start server again. If I don't start Jboss inside Eclipse, I won't get a seamless debugging integration.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, currently there is no way to attach a script to execute before running JBoss (assuming you use *JBoss AS Tools*).

However, you can indirectly achieve it using below steps:

1. Write a script that does the assembling (let's call it
   `auto-assemble.bat`)
2. Select your project > menubar: Project >
   Properties
3. Select Builders in the left pane
4. Click `New...` button on the right pane
5. Select Program > OK
6. Give appropriate Name
7. Browse and select the `auto-assemble.bat` file > Apply > OK and close the dialog

From now on whenever you want to assemble the EAR simply do the following:

1. Make some changes to your code (optional)
2. Do Project > Clean (optional if you do step 1)
3. Do Project > Build Project (if Build Automatically is not enabled)
4. Run the JBoss